# C++ Shogun library: Cannot locate shogun/lib/config.h file

Tags: c++, shogun

I am reading through the [shogun C++ library code](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun) and while reading in the `src` folder, I notice that many files include the header file `shogun/lib/config.h`, but I cannot find this header file in the source code.

For example, if you look at the header file [SGMatrix.h](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/develop/src/shogun/lib/SGMatrix.cpp) you can clearly see that it has the following include statement:

```
#include <shogun/lib/config.h>
```

yet you can't find `config.h` anywhere in `shogun/lib`. Where can I find this header file?

Answer (score 1):

The `config.h` is being created during configuration, i.e. running cmake, and the actual content is based on your system's properties. the template of for the file can be found in `src/shogun/lib/config.h.in`